# Popping from a list & Subtracting from a Function (Hangman)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I've am having trouble with the last two specifications of this program.

1) Guesser initially gets 6 misses (7th strike and they are out). If they win that game, they play again, but with only 5 misses, etc. The game ends when they fail to guess the word in the specified number of guesses or until they win a game in which they have 0 misses.

*- I've tried but I don't know how to have all of my numbers from the other functions reflect the new change. I would like to keep the option to replay so they can quit at anytime.*

2) Before each guess display a list of letters that have not yet been guessed.

*- I know this one is simpler and I should know it but I think I've fried my brain.*

I've still have documentation to do so I apologize for any errors.  Any cleanup is always appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
import random
import string

word_list = ["no", "hi", "bee", "car", "seat", "bear", "see", "chip"]
available_letters = string.ascii_lowercase  # pop guessed letter from here
used_letters = []  # Add it to here, and display avaiable_letters each time a letter is guessed.


missed_letters = ""
correct_letters = ""
secret_word = random.choice(word_list).lower()


def get_random(word_list):

    secret_word = random.choice(word_list).lower()
    return secret_word


def display_board(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word):

    print("Current Score:")

    for letter in missed_letters:
        print(letter)
    print()

    blanks = '-' * len(secret_word)

    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
            if secret_word[i] in correct_letters:
                blanks = blanks[:i] + secret_word[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter)
    print()


def get_player_guess(guessed):

    while True:
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")  # try guess = input(blah blah).lower()
        guess = guess.lower()

        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("1 Letter at a time!")
        elif guess in guessed:
            print("Whoops, you already guessed that one!")
        elif guess not in "abcdefghijklomnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print("Letters only please!")
        else:
            return guess


def replay_game():

    replay = input("Do you want to play again? y or n ")

    if replay == "y":
        play_game(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word)
    else:
        print("Bye!")


def play_game(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word):

    count = 0
    chance = 7
    game_over = False

    print("Welcome To Hangman.")

    while True:
        display_board(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word)

        guess = get_player_guess(missed_letters + correct_letters)

        if guess in secret_word:

            correct_letters = correct_letters + guess

            done = True

            for i in range(len(secret_word)):
                    if secret_word[i] not in correct_letters:
                        done = False
                        break

            if done:
                print("You win!")
                game_over = True
        else:

            missed_letters = missed_letters + guess

            count += 1
            chance -= 1

            if count == 1:
                print("You've got " + str(count) + " Strike. You have " + str(chance) + " Chances left")
            elif count > 1 and count < 6:
                print("You've got " + str(count) + " Strikes.  You have " + str(chance) + " Chances left")
            elif count == 6 and chance == 1:
                print("You've got " + str(count) + " Strikes.  You have " + str(chance) + " Chance left")

            if len(missed_letters) == 7:

                display_board(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word)

                print("Sorry!  You've run out of guesses! The right word was " + secret_word + "!")

                game_over = True

        if game_over:

            if replay_game():
                missed_letters = ""
                correct_letters = ""
                secret_word = get_random(word_list)

            else:
                break


play_game(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word)
```

Comment: Looking at your previous questions it looks like you always post your homework on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you aren't changing the word when replay_game is called because the text after `if replay_game` at the end is never being called.

For the first problem, I would record the total number of chances for the game as an input variable into play_game and change replay_game to just return true or false and move the other code into play_game

```
def replay_game():

    replay = input("Do you want to play again? y or n ")
    # Changed to just return true or false depending on input.
    if replay == "y":
        return True
    else:
        print("Bye!")
        return False
```

Then change the start of play_game to

```
def play_game(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word, total_chances=7):

    count = 0
    # chance is now variable
    chance = total_chances
    game_over = False
```

and at the end of `play_game`, replace:

```
if len(missed_letters) == 7:
```

with

```
if chance == 0:
```

and change the call to `if game_over` to

```
if game_over:

    if replay_game():
        missed_letters = ""
        correct_letters = ""
        secret_word = get_random(word_list)
        play_game(missed_letters, correct_letters, secret_word, total_chances - 1)

    else:
        break
```

This will mean your code which was resetting the letters will get called now, and each restarted game starts with one less chance than the previous.

You'll have to add some handling for the case where they win with no misses allowed.

For the second problem, just add the following to display board:

```
print("Available letters:")
print(','.join(sorted(set(available_letters) - set(missed_letters) - set(correct_letters))))
```

This makes a set of each of the three groups of letters, and then takes away those already guessed, before displaying them in one line, alphabetically sorted and comma separated.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried it and everything seems to be in order, and most of all makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the function display_board I would clean the code a bit to substitute the '_' in blanks with the correct letter when it was correctly guessed:

```
for i in range(len(secret_word)):
            if secret_word[i] in correct_letters:
                blanks[i] = secret_word[i]
```

It looks cleaner and does less reassignments of elements in blanks.